# How to pass 'n' arrays to a method in C# and print is CSV File

Tags: c#, object, parameters

Imagine a CSV file, with the headers for the fields in the first row and values on the next rows, all of the same size.

for example these would be headers

```
area,hotelnames,zipcode,state
```

and these the values

```
200,star,93117,CA
230,2Star,93116,CA
```

I need to make a common method which would accept the data and write it in the mentioned way to a CSV file. The values are passed as arrays and can contain data of any type.

Comment: Not clear to me what the exact question is but if you need help reading/writing a csv like that have a look at a library called FileHelpers found at http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate CSV file then use a library that was written to do just that. Don't reinvent the wheel ;-)

Use **FileHelpers** library that **Eddy** suggested in the comments under your question.

Comment: I know how to read and write into CSV Files but Currently i have some 50 test files having a method which collects the  different type(double array and string array)data and printed in CSV file. I want to improve these tests by writing a single generic method to pass all these parameters to be printed in CSV file,Such that we can avoid the common methods used in 50 different tests.